# How to use PrimeReact's Button component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, primereact

I am trying out the javascript map method whilst building a simple calculator.

I am using a list for each row of the calculator and mapping it to a table cell and a prime react button inside it.

I am however getting weird results in the browser.

My code in the component is below and I have screenshotted the output.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0VFI.png)

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Button} from 'primereact/button'

class Calculator extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    const values1 = ["7", "8", "9", "/"]
    const values2 = ["4", "5", "6", "x"]
    const values3 = ["1", "2", "3", "-"]
    const values4 = ["0", ".", "+", "="]
    const valuesList1 = values1.map(value => <td><Button>{value}</Button></td>)
    const valuesList2 = values2.map(value => <td><Button>{value}</Button></td>)
    const valuesList3 = values3.map(value => <td><Button>{value}</Button></td>)
    const valuesList4 = values4.map(value => <td><Button>{value}</Button></td>)

    return (
      <div className="Middle">
        <section className="InputContainer">
          <table className="Keys">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                {valuesList1}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                {valuesList2}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                {valuesList3}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                {valuesList4}
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Calculator;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem may be coming from the `<Button/>` component as it renders additional text that seems to be its `className` within it.

I see you are using the PrimeReact library for the button and according to their [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/button), you should enter the button's text via the `label` prop.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Button} from 'primereact/button'

class Calculator extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    const values1 = ["7", "8", "9", "/"]
    const values2 = ["4", "5", "6", "x"]
    const values3 = ["1", "2", "3", "-"]
    const values4 = ["0", ".", "+", "="]
    const valuesList1 = values1.map(value => <td><Button label={value} /></td>)
    const valuesList2 = values2.map(value => <td><Button label={value} /></td>)
    const valuesList3 = values3.map(value => <td><Button label={value} /></td>)
    const valuesList4 = values4.map(value => <td><Button label={value} /></td>)

    return (
      <div className="Middle">
        <section className="InputContainer">
          <table className="Keys">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                {valuesList1}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                {valuesList2}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                {valuesList3}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                {valuesList4}
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Calculator;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Worked thanks man! Ill be sure to keep an eye on the documentation next time!